# VBA Boolean Function type mismatch on return

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have searched here all morning, but see nothing like this particular error.  While debugging an Excel VBA macro I'm getting a very frustrating run-time error - type mismatch `13` error when assigning the return value of function 'Display_Form' to the boolean variable 'success'. The form displays and behaves properly, but upon exiting the form and then the calling function, this error pops up.  Here is the code. I'm hitting a wall with this one.  Any ideas?

```
Public Sub Add_New_Account()
    ' Process userforms to create new Bank account

    Dim success As Boolean
    
    success = Display_Form(NewAccountForm1)
    If success Then
        Select Case accountDict(ACCT_TYPE_HEADER)
            Case CREDIT_CD, CREDIT_IFL, CREDIT_DEPT
            Case BANK_CHK, BANK_SAV
                ' Nothing needed at this time
        End Select
    End If
    
End Sub
```

```
Public Function Display_Form(targetForm As Object, Optional leftPos As Integer = 0, Optional topPos As Integer = 0) As Boolean
    ' Open the 'targetForm' userform
    Display_Form = True
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler

    With ActiveSheet
        Load targetForm
        With targetForm
          .StartUpPosition = 0
          If leftPos Then
            .Left = leftPos
          Else
            .Left = Application.Left + Application.Width - .Width
          End If
          If topPos Then
            .Top = topPos
          Else
            .Top = Application.Top + Application.Height - .Height
          End If
          .Show vbModal
        End With
        Unload targetForm
    End With
    Exit Function
    
ErrorHandler:
    ' Handle Ctrl-Break gracefully
    If Err.Number = 18 Then
        MsgBox "Use the Cancel button instead of Ctrl-Break"
        Resume
    Else
        ' Some other error occurred
        MsgBox "Sorry, something went wrong: " & vbNewLine & _
             Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
             "Macro ended unexpectedly.", vbExclamation
        Display_Form = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of your function returning a value? It doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: You'd need to pass `targetForm` `ByVal`, but why are you reloading the form in the function and then destroying it? Either don't pass it as an argument, or don't load/destroy it in the function.

Comment: Also, if `NewAccountForm1` is the name of the form, you should be using a variable, not the default instance.

Comment: Prob not absolutely necessary to return a value, but I use it to let me know if an error was trapped in the function.  I can step through it using F8 - the error occurs when success = Display_Form(NewAccountForm1) is executed

Comment: This is an intermediate form. The form code validates input, then saves it to a dictionary for later use. It doesn't appear that how the form is passed here is the issue - the form is loading, displaying, and unloading properly. The type mismatch error appears at the point where the function value (verified by stepping through the code in debug mode) is assigned to the variable success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a work-around rather than an explanation, seems to work for me

```
Dim success As Boolean, oForm as object

set oForm = NewAccountForm1
success = Display_Form(oForm)
```

Might prompt someone else to know why

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - that did the trick. I added the new variable, set it = NewAccountForm1 in the calling routine, and added ByRef to the param in the function def. Would love to know why this was necessary, but I suspect it is related to Rory's comment about using a variable instead of the default instance. Another case of the run-time error message not pointing directly to the cause, I guess.

Comment: I thought your UnLoad might have caused the problem but it arose for me without using load/unload and just using .Show